# Passing parameters from one PHP to WEB SITE

Tags: php, html, bash, post

I am setting a parameters in my PHP page and need to pass it to another WEB SITE, to execute operation on the WEB SITE (i don't need to get re result). I use `header ("location : https://localhost/test=123")` but its not executing it and display:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/script1.php:33) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/script1.php on line 106
```

How can i simply just invoke it one time?

if there is solution from bash file,also can help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506155/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by) and [oh so very many others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already output content to use header().
I would recommend:

```
$sRemotePage = file_get_contents('https://localhost/test=123');
```

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 2):

The header function can only be used before ANY output is displayed on the screen.
For example:

```
 <?php
    echo( 'test' );
    header('location: www.google.com');
 ?>
```

Would fail with that error you reported.

Comment: thanks, i cancel all the `echo` and its worked! Can i do it without actually be redirected to that site?

Comment: As stated in one of the answers below, file_get_contents() would send a request to the given URL, without redirecting you to the site.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HTTP `meta` element to set where the browser redirects the user. It needs to look like this:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost/test=123">
```

Where `0` is the number of seconds the browser will wait before redirecting, and `url` is the redirected URL.

The other option would be using [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but I am not entirely sure what you want to do and whether it can include `ob_` or not.